# How to create two excel lines from one line

Tags: talend

I'm a beginner on Talend Studio.

**My problem**

I don't know how to create two lines from one line.

I have an excel file with these columns: `LastName, FirstName, Course1, Course2, Results`.

**My objective**

My objective is to create an excel output file but with a column named `Course`.

So my header will be `LastName, FirstName, Course`.

My input file contains 40 lines. So my output file must contains 80 lines.

**My actual structure**

I'm using `tFileExcelInput`, `tMap` and `tFileExcelOutput`.

[image: actual structure]

Here, `OutConc_1_` is `Course1`. And `AnalDon_1_` is `Course2`.

Finally, `Note` is the global column (`Course`).

**Error**

However, when I do these joins, I get this error:

> Compilation error : AnalDon_1_ cannot be resolved or is not a field.

(If I join firstly `AnalDon_1_` and then `OutConc_1_`, the error is: `OutConc_1_ cannot be resolved or is not a field`.)

**Example**

*Input file*

```
LastName,FirstName,Course1,Course2,Result
John,Test,10,15,12.5
Mike,Dupond,6,9,7.5
```

*Result excepted*:

```
LastName,FirstName,Course
John,Test,10
John,Test,15
Mike,Dupond,6
Mike,Dupond,9
```

Thank's for help.

Comment: You were so close ! Just concatenate the two columns together and you're good to go ! `row1.OutConc_1_ + row1.AnalDon_1_`

Comment: Where I have to do that? I must create a new colum on the left side and concatenate the two colunms into it?

Comment: Nope, in the expression field of your Note column, just change the expression "row1.OutConc_1_ row1.AnalDon_1_" to "row1.OutConc_1_ + row1.AnalDon_1_"

Comment: Yes but that regroup both columns... I updated my post with an example. I hope my previous post was enought clear.

Comment: Ah I see, I thought you meant to concatenate both columns :)
I'll answer you question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want each row to generate two rows in the target. One row where Course is Course1, and a 2nd row where Course is Course2. You can do this :

[image]

Use `tSplitRow` to generate 2 rows from each input row (notice that only `Note` column is different between the 2 rows). If you need to add another column to the `Note` output column, just add a row to `tSplitRow` and map it with the values you want.

Comment: Amazing!!! Thank's a lot! Now I have to find how to get an excel column name to set `Matiere` and my job is done. Thank's again!

Comment: You're welcome ! you can always ask another question if you're stuck ;)

Comment: Yes now I have to set `Matiere` with `OutConc_1_` or `AnalDon_1_` according to `Note`. I hope that it's possible, and if it is, I hope I will find it ahah.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.. If you can't figure it out, just post another question with the details and I'll look into it ;)

Comment: I posted a new question because I didn't find solution myself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752841/get-an-excel-column-name-to-set-a-case-value