# How to get an excel column name to set a case value

Tags: talend

It is possible to get an excel column name to set a case value?

Not a best way to show you my expectation than with an example.

**Example**

*Input excel file*

```
LastName,FirstName,Maths,IT
John,Polo,10,15
Mike,Dupond,6,9
```

*Result excepted*

```
LastName,FirstName,Course,Grade
John,Polo,Maths,10
John,Polo,IT,15
Mike,Dupond,Maths,6
Mike,Dupond,IT,9
```

**Here my actual Talend structure**

[image]

Currently, this structure allow me to obtain this result:

```
LastName,FirstName,Course,Grade
John,Polo,"",10
John,Polo,"",15
Mike,Dupond,"",6
Mike,Dupond,"",9
```

Thank's for help!

Comment: Hi again. Do you know in advance the structure of your excel file ? (will you always have Maths and IT as columns ?)

Comment: Hi again! :) On this case yes I know the structure. For this file it is Maths and IT, but for another file it can be Spannish and English. So I will change file by file.

Comment: The solution find is to set `Course` into `tSplitRow` config.

Comment: Yes, since you don't have variable columns, it's just like my answer to your previous question

Comment: Yes of course, it is not a generic method but it works :) Thanks!